# Linux search string in a file with space

Tags: grep

Im trying to figure out how to search a string in Linux i hope someone can help me out.

```
grep "Test\|Account" test.txt
```

The above command works if i only want to search for one word.
But when i try to search "Create Test 'account'" not sure how to use grep since im a newbie in Linux.

Comment: a space is not in any way a special character, so it just works the same.

Comment: What is the problem? `grep -F "Create Test 'account'" test.txt`?

Comment: Welcome  Yajnos, this forum is asking technical questions. If you are seeking for training with `grep` command please refer to: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/grep-command-tutorial-how-to-search-for-a-file-in-linux-and-unix/

Comment: So what is the problem? Looking for fixed strings?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem with backticks? What is your real problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion work grep -F "Create Test 'account'" test.txt
but when i search for grep -F "Create Test `account`" test.txt there will be no result.
You already answered my original problem this one is different i didn't expect there will be `` character in other files.

Comment: So, you want to match either `"Create Test 'account'"` or ``"Create Test `account`"``, right?

Answer (score 0):

With a GNU `grep`, you can use

```sh
grep "Create Test 'account'\|Create Test \`account\`" test.txt
```

Here, the backticks are escaped since they are used inside a double quoted string where they are evaluated. The `|` regex alternation operator is escaped because it is considered a literal pipe char otherwise.

*Details*:

- `Create Test 'account'` - a literal text
- `\|` - or
- `` Create Test `account` `` - a literal text